# Error for the site owner Google site owner

Tags: javascript, shopify, recaptcha

I am stuck to the following problem and getting error on recaptcha.
The error which is i am getting is "ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key". Can any one respolve the problem. Here is the screenshot and attached code in shopify which I am using.

[image]

```
 <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<div class="row">
  {% include 'custom_breadcrumb' %}
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="sidebar-pages">
      {% include 'sidebar-pages' %}
    </div>
          <!--     side bar condition for Happiness Guarantee page  -->
      {% if page.handle == "100-happiness-guarantee" %}
      <div class="sidbar_imges">
        <a href="/pages/100-happiness-guarantee"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2502/0332/files/happiness_guarantee_22cf74cf-9eca-4155-b710-f90e45d3ee5d.png?11766646048781568141" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      {% else %}

      {% endif %}

   <!-- end condition     -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="page-content">
         {{ page.content }}
     </div>
    {% if page.handle == "contact" %}
hghf
    <div class="contact-form form-vertical custom_contact">
        {% form 'contact' %}

          {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
            <p class="note form-success">
              {{ 'contact.form.post_success' | t }}
            </p>
          {% endif %}

          {{ form.errors | default_errors }}

          <div class="grid grid--half-gutters">
            <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
              <label for="ContactFormName">{{ 'contact.form.name' | t }}</label>
              <input type="text" id="ContactFormName" name="contact[name]" value="{% if form[name] %}{{ form[name] }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.name }}{% endif %}">
            </div>
            <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
              <label for="ContactFormEmail" class="{% if form.errors contains 'email' %}label--error{% endif %}">{{ 'contact.form.email' | t }}</label>
              <input type="email" id="ContactFormEmail" name="contact[email]" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" value="{% if form.email %}{{ form.email }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.email }}{% endif %}" class="{% if form.errors contains 'email' %}input--error{% endif %}">
            </div>
          </div>

          <label for="ContactFormPhone">{{ 'contact.form.phone' | t }}</label>
          <input type="tel" id="ContactFormPhone" name="contact[phone]" pattern="[0-9\-]*" value="{% if form[phone] %}{{ form[phone] }}{% elsif customer %}{{ customer.phone }}{% endif %}">

          <label for="ContactFormMessage">{{ 'contact.form.message' | t }}</label>
          <textarea rows="10" id="ContactFormMessage" name="contact[body]">{% if form.body %}{{ form.body }}{% endif %}</textarea>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LecFDgUAAAAACl_oTnHA6zmvTv5v1ubdXyLVcgp"></div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ 'contact.form.submit' | t }}">

        {% endform %}
      </div>
{% else %}
{% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API key is invalid. Generate a new one.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#recently-my-recaptcha-widget-started-displaying-invalid-site-key-whats-happening